# get current url and pass part of it as variable

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to write optimized .htaccess rules. I had written like that and they are working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^city1-name-in-url/$ products.php?city=city1-name-in-url
RewriteRule ^city2-name-in-url/$ products.php?city=city2-name-in-url
RewriteRule ^city3-name-in-url/$ products.php?city=city3-name-in-url
RewriteRule ^city4-name-in-url/$ products.php?city=city4-name-in-url
```

And url for these rules are `http://www.example.com/global/city1-name-in-url/`

I have to write these rules for 800 cities which is making website slow. I want to know if there is anyway to get the part url and use it in `RewriteRule`

Example like

If url : `http://www.example.com/global/any-city-name/`

`RewriteRule ^any-city-name/$ products.php?city=any-city-name`

This is possible? To get the part of url after `global` and then use it in rewrite rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/global/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ products.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`[\w-]+` matches 1 or more of `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` characters.

Comment: thankyou for your answer :), but your solution isn't working. Also can you please add some description how the regex is supposed to work ?

Comment: Added some explanation. What URL did you enter to test and where is htaccess located?

Comment: global is directory & htaccess file is located within this directory

Comment: Please add a little about why

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f `

should be added

Comment: Added inline comments for more clarity.